# Configuring Python in Aptana to push output to console window

Tags: python, aptana

I have very recently been learning python.  I have been using pyscripter as is demonstrated over on kahnacademy, but after finding some bugs in pyscripter decided to upgrade to a much more robust coding environ, hence aptana studio.

Right now I have python installed properly, it will run scripts, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get it to output print commands to the console window at the bottom.

To test this my script is simply:

```
print "hello"
```

The console gives me:

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... done.

---------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

I know I am missing something really simple here but I haven't the foggiest what it could be.
I would like to see the python console output only - what could I be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using the 'run unit-tests' launch instead of the regular launch. For a regular launch, just press F9 on the file you're editing and it should work. Also, if you still haven't, read the PyDev getting started guide: http://pydev.org/manual_101_root.html (or at least http://pydev.org/manual_101_run.html, which is the part related to your problem, and it'll also explain how to config Ctrl+F11 to relaunch your last launch, etc).

Comment: This is exactly what I was doing.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Aptana uses PyDev.
To run modules (.py) files in debug mode you need to tell the file what function you want to execute. Try this template when testing:

```
def main():
    print "Hello world"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```